# write "strict mode" it in one place to get it effect on all `.js` file code

Tags: javascript, razor, ecmascript-6

I have a `cshtml` page which have lot of `.js` file, I am testing my `.js` to run in `strict mode`. I have to write `"use strict"` on each `.js` file. Can I write it in one place to get it effect on all `.js` file code.
May be in `.cshtml`, But it does not work.

Comment: You could use ESLint's `strict` rule with the `--fix` argument to have ESLint automatically add it for you.

Answer (score 1):

No.

"A script" (represented by the content of a `<script>` element or a `.js` file) is the widest scope to which `"use strict"` can be applied.